# How do I make a Kendo Menu open on hover, not on click?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-menu

I have a Kendo menu as my main menu, with config starting like

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("main-menu")
    .OpenOnClick(false)
    .Items(items1 =>
```

Finding no other config option, I thought making `OpenOnClick` false would make some magical `OpenonHover` true. I want menu items with children to open on hover so that I can get rid of the arrow to the right of the parent menu item text, as there is absolutely no spacing between the arrow and the tick. I have unsuccessfully tried the `:before` and `:after' pseudo-selectors to insert space, to no avail. All I could get inserted was a literal` " hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfhHW/36/). FYI-it's using jQuery, not using `Html helper`. Hope it's helpful to you.

You can open menu on hover.